# Detect if input box 'string' value is bigger than input itself

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to detect if input text value/string width is bigger than input itself. I want to apply some addtional styles if all the text in input is not visible.

The font size can be dynamic so I can't convert each char to pixels.

Appreciate any feedback. This needs to work only in IE.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834445/detect-if-text-in-an-input-type-text-element-exceeds-bounds-in-firefox ?

Comment: You could mesure the size of your string (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21015393/4734683) and compare it to your input size, minus your left and right padding of course !

Comment: There is workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209831/detect-if-text-overflowellipsis-is-active-on-input-field