# How to conditionally add "fade to black" mask to input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm implementing a design where a "fade to black" mask is expected to appear on the left side of the input once the text content reachs the maximum visible width of the input box.

The image bellow illustrates better what I'm trying to acomplish:
[image]

I already implemented part of it, with the code below:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#input');
var container = document.querySelector('.myInput');

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (input.value.length > 12) {
    container.classList.add('faded');
  } else {
    container.classList.remove('faded');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.myInput {
  position: relative;
}

.myInput input {
  font-family: "Trim", "NOW G", "Oscine";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 28px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
}

.faded::before {
  display: block;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 15px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myInput">
  <input id="input" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
```

My problem now is how to add this mask conditionally (that is, removing the hardcoded 12 chars length and the input hardcoded width) and also, how to create a responsible solution that will work with all widths and all text sizes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if it's an exact dupe but perhaps this is helpful: [Detect if text in an input element exceeds bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834445/detect-if-text-in-an-input-type-text-element-exceeds-bounds-in-firefox). It puts the input's text in a placeholder element, fetches the width, and compares it to the input to determine if the text is overflowing or not.

Comment: Interesting approach @TylerRoper, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find if the `input` is overflown as

`(input.offsetWidth < input.scrollWidth)`

Also I'd recommend listening to `input` event instead of `keydown` to catch `paste` as well.

See the snippet below:

```js
document.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
    var input = e.target;
    var container = input.parentNode;
    if (input.offsetWidth < input.scrollWidth) {
      if (!container.classList.contains('faded')) {
        container.classList.add('faded');
        var cs = getComputedStyle(input);
        container.querySelector('.shadow').style.left = [
          'border-left-width', 'margin-left', 'padding-left'
        ].reduce(function(a, e) {
          return a += parseInt(cs[e])
        }, 0) + 'px';
      }
    } else {
      container.classList.remove('faded');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.myInput {
  position: relative;
  margin:1rem;
}

.myInput input {
  font: normal 500 28px "Trim", "NOW G", "Oscine";
  background: #000;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
}

.faded .shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

#input2 {
  margin-left: 20%;
  padding-left: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="myInput">
  <input id="input" placeholder="Search" />
  <span class="shadow"></span>
</div>


<div class="myInput">
  <input id="input2" placeholder="Search" />
  <span class="shadow"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's very nice, thanks for your response and for the "input" event tip. However, I'm still having problems to make it work with different input padding values (considering that I'll not know what is the input css beforehand)

Comment: @GuilhermeLemmi, your question did not mention any `padding` problems... But I've solved this. See my updated answer.

Comment: @GuilhermeLemmi, happy to help.