# How to get a string width

Tags: c#, string

I need to build a function in a class library that take a string and a specific font for this string then get the width of the string

So how could I get the string boundary width ?

Comment: Could be merged with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553965/programmatically-measure-string-in-asp-net

Comment: Measuring the size of a string for a website sounds questionable.  There is no way to tell what size the browser is going to display the font AFAIK.

Comment: A specific font is not enough to know this. You also need to know which renderer will display the text. For example Apple and MS render text very differently, and I wouldn't be surprised if that affected the graphical width of a text. If you try to get the width of text displayed in html on the server-side(as your tags seem to imply) that's most likely not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string length to a pixel unit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451903/how-can-i-convert-a-string-length-to-a-pixel-unit)

Answer (score 18):

Another way to do this is with a `TextRenderer`, and call *its* [`MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66.aspx) method, passing the string and the font type.

**MSDN Example:**

```
private void MeasureText1(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    String text1 = "Measure this text";
    Font arialBold = new Font("Arial", 12.0F);
    Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text1, arialBold);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text1, arialBold, 
        new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), textSize), Color.Red);  
}
```

**NOTE:** This is just an alternate solution to the (equally valid) one already posted by @Neil Barnwell
 (in case you already have a reference to System.Windows.Forms in your project, this might be more convenient).

Comment: I think this just work within a windows application not class library project !

Comment: @AshOoO I agree, that's what the note at the end of my answer is all about =)

Comment: This will measure the text size on current Form. If you need to measure the text size for example on printer output, you will need to use `e.Graphics.MeasureString(...)` method.

Answer (score 13):

You can get a `Graphics` object (using [Control.CreateGraphics()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) on the container you intend the text for) and call `MeasureString()` to do this. It's a fairly common GDI+ 
technique.

More information from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx

Comment: AFAIK GDI+ text measurements are a bit problematic. In particular when using the size to center text that doesn't work as desired.

Comment: I use the `MeasureString` method and now I got a return value with type of SizeF then got it to PointF and I know now the width but in PointF >>> I need it in cm ! I try to convert it as I think the PointF is like the Postscript point but I think my converting formula is not correct >> so How to convert after get the poinf width !?

Comment: `PointF` is just a `float` value for a `Point` (i.e. non-integral values). Converting from points to centimetres should be doable (points->pixels->dpi->inches->cm?) but why do you need centimetres?

Comment: My actual case is that I need to draw a string in a specific rectangle width ,So I need to check first if my string fit the rectangle width as if not it will wrap but in a formated way

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
private float getTextSize(string text)
    {
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 10.0F);
        Image fakeImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(fakeImage);
        SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(text, font);
        return size.Width;
    }
```

Comment: this is way faster than TextRenderer

Comment: I have to admit it, the fake image was a brilliant idea; one can cache it for subsequent calls and save the allocation/collection cycle.