# How to find string's width in C# (in pixels)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to achieve framed texts (using Windows Forms), e.g.:

[image]

Height is always the same, because my strings are less than 20 chars. What about width? Is there any way to get it automatically?

Comment: possible duplipcate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714022/how-to-get-a-string-width

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string length to a pixel unit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451903/how-can-i-convert-a-string-length-to-a-pixel-unit)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `Graphics.MeasureString()`

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx

```
private void MeasureStringMin(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Set up string. 
    string measureString = "Measure String";
    Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);

    // Measure string.
    SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
    stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);

    // Draw rectangle representing size of string.
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), 0.0F, 0.0F, stringSize.Width, stringSize.Height);

    // Draw string to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(measureString, stringFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you don't feel like dealing with the Paint eventhandler, you could try the `TextRenderer` class. It has a static method that is identical to the `MeasureString()` method in the above answer. In this class it is called `MeasureText` however.