# autosize node width for d3 tree layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Please suggest on how to autosize the width of the node according the node value for d3 tree layout.

The following is the link reference I adapted and piece of code.

```
var margin = {
top: 20,
right: 120,
bottom: 20,
left: 120
},
width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/augburto/YMa2y/

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- do you want to autosize the SVG?

Comment: Have you tried to play with the `tree.value()` function?

Comment: If you check the above link I have referenced to, and then click on tree --> flare, analytics,and cluster...you will see the node names under cluster have come out of the node and are jumbled.  I would want to autosize the node width according to the value that is in it...so that there wil no overlapping

Comment: @ChristopherChiche...I tried using both value and size, but in vain...$array = '{"name":"'.$name.'","value":'.strlen($name).',"children":[' etc.....

Answer (score 0):

I haven't answered your exact question, but essentially you to need to dynamically auto size the svg rectangle.  I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/279PX/) to dynamically sizing the rectangle based on the number of children, using this code:

```
> .attr("width", function (d,i) { if(d._children) console.log(rectW +
> d._children.length);
>         return d._children ? (rectW + d._children.length) : rectW; })
```

Which simply adds the length of the number of children to the rectW.  For what you want to do you need to calculate the length of the text and set that to the width of the rectangle.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254644/get-pixel-length-of-string-in-svg) might help you calculate the length of the text. You'll also have to recalculate the centre of the rectangle to place the label.

Hope this gets you going.

Cheers