# How to extend the width of a td if there are line breaks in the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table with some long texts and some short texts. If a `<td>` contains a long text I would like to increase the width.

This is what I tried to do:

```
var text = $('td').text().split('\n');
if(text.length === 1) {
    $(this).css('width','270px');
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dsc4m/2/)
I tried to get the number of line breaks with `alert(text.length)` and i get 1. Then if there is 1 line break I added `.css('width','270px')`, but doesn't work. What I did wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: you have spelt `lenght` wrong - it should be `length`

Comment: Do you need `table-layout:fixed;`? Without it, it would correctly adjust the size of the columns according to the content within http://jsfiddle.net/tytUS/

Comment: Thanks @smj2393 I have corrected but this is not the problem.

Comment: I think `this` might have the wrong scope. You want extend the `td` as soon as it has a linebreak?

Comment: @MackieeE I need to use `table-layout:fixed;` because I want to get `word-break: break-word;` on td.

Comment: @Fuiba I don't see why you need that CSS rule when that's the very thing you're trying to prevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your fiddle I guess that you cannot use `split('\n')` to detect if the text breaks into multiple lines because those line breaks are automatically inserted by the browser for layout purposes and they don't exist as `\n` in the text.

I would suggest to compare the rendered height of the cell to calculate the number of lines inside.

**UPDATE**

Thanks Bill, that was a good point. The cells in each row are always of equal height. The first solution that came to my mind was to use wrapper divs inside the cells. They only expand as much as needed to display the text. It's not "nice" but it seems to do the job: http://jsfiddle.net/dsc4m/7/

Comment: Ah, another interesting hypothesis!

Comment: Nice to hear it helped you. I was wondering why you didn't go for auto-layout on this table...? The browser expands the line if necessary.

Comment: I just tried updating my answer... All the cells heights would be the same. You might need to do it based on the amount of characters in the cell's text.

Comment: @ToniTornado Here's my little fiddle if you care to mess around with it to update your answer since it's marked as accepted. http://jsfiddle.net/dsc4m/6/

Comment: @Bill I don't think you can use the number of characters. Consider WWWWWWW and lllllll are of the same length. This question is about getting the length in pixels: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057682/determine-pixel-length-of-string-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: Agreed. I think the wrapper div is sadly a better approach that still stinks.

Answer (score 2):

I took a stab at what I *think* you are trying to do:

```
var $tds = $('td');

$tds.each(function(){

    var $td = $(this), length = $.trim($td.text()).length;

    if( length > 22 ) {
        $td.css('background-color', 'red');
    }

});
```

If not this should get you a lot closer to your goal. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsc4m/6/

Comment: No problem. Glad everyone was able to get things sorted out!