# Word wrap in table changes cell size

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, css-tables

I have a table with 2 columns, one of which has `word-wrap: break-word`:

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

table td:nth-child(2) {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column1</td>
        <td>Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to keep the first column's width to a minimum, and the second column expanding to fit the rest of the table.

But `word-wrap: break-word` only works if I set `table-layout: fixed` and that forces all columns to have equal dimensions. How can I achieve what I want without explicitly setting a width value on the first column?

Comment: I don't have CSS solution for this. Just one Jquery trick, based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057682/determine-pixel-length-of-string-in-javascript-jquery Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/xgk455xr/ Basically, you must set width, but it is set dynamically this way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using the `width` attribute of the `<td>` like below.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
table td:nth-child(2) {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column1</td>
    <td>Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2Column2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my question, I don't want to set a width on either column, since I don't know how much content there will be.

Comment: Oops, i missed the last sentence sorry. So, do you want to make the first column fit the longest word it contains?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.

Comment: @Atlas23250 I have edited my answer. I hope that's the behavior that you expect? Yeah giving pixel values for the entire `table` is not a good idea. My edited answer is better I hope.

Comment: Nicely done! Adding a `max-width` value, that's very clever. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just add a single bit of css,code is displayed under,try it

```
table td {
border: 1px solid blue;
}

table td:nth-child(1) {
width:100px;   //your value
}

table td:nth-child(2) {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Hope this will enough for you

Regds..