# Making a never ending marquee animation css3

Tags: php, html, css

Hi I have successfully made a marquee transition in css3 which scrolls my sql data from my website and database but the only issue I have is that I would like it so there is never any space under it and it constantly keeps going can anybody help please below is my code and css

[Live Preview Here](http://rbgraphix.co.uk/feedback.php)

Thanks in advance

```css
  display:block;
  width: 500px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: marquee;
  -webkit-animation-name: marquee; 
  animation-duration: 60s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-direction:normal;
  -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
    #marquee:hover {
     -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }

@keyframes marquee {
  from { top: 100%; }
  to { top: 0%; }
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    from {top: 100%;}
    to {top: 0%;}
 }
```

```html
<div id="main">
        <div class="marquee">
          <?php
require('connect.php');
$run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");

 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($run);
 if($numrows > 0){
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
  $dbname = $row['name'];
  $dbrating = $row['rating'];
  $dbwebsite = $row['website'];
  $dbservice = $row['service'];
        $dbdate = $row['postdate'];
  $dbcomment = $row['comment'];
  $newDate = date("l dS F Y", strtotime($dbdate));
?>   

<div id="commenttop">
 <div id="userdetails"><?php echo "{$dbname} - {$dbservice}" ?></div>
  <div id="rating">
  <?php 
if ($dbrating == 1) {
  echo '<img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /> <img src="images/star.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />';
}

if ($dbrating == 2) {
  echo '<img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /> <img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" />';
}

if ($dbrating == 3) {
  echo '<img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /> <img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" />';
}

if ($dbrating == 4) {
  echo '<img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /> <img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" />';
}

if ($dbrating == 5) {
  echo '<img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /> <img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" />';
}
?>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="commentbtm"><?php echo "$dbcomment"?>
<div id="date"><?php echo $newDate?></div>
</div>

<?php 
        }
 }
 else
  echo "No Comments Found";
?>

        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find or recode a solution to this original query using css3 so instead I decided to go with Javascript and it works exactly how I wanted it too :) for those of you that may have a solution to the original post for future reference please do let me know thankyou below you will find the code I used for those of you wishing to do similar good luck.

```js
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    function go() {
        i = i < height ? i + step : 1;
        m.style.marginTop = -i + 'px';
    }
    var i = 0,
        step = 3,
        space = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    var m = document.getElementById('marquee');
    var t = m.innerHTML; //text
    m.innerHTML = t + space;
    m.style.position = 'absolute'; // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057682/determine-pixel-length-of-string-in-javascript-jquery/2057789#2057789
    var height = (m.clientHeight + 1);
    m.style.position = '';
    m.innerHTML = t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space;
    m.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
        step = 0;
    }, true);
    m.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
        step = 3;
    }, true);
    var x = setInterval(go, 50);
}, true);
</script>
```

```css
#marquee {
  border:1px solid #007df8;
  display:block;
  width: 500px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">  
        <div id="marquee"> 
        <div>  
          <?php  
require('connect.php');  
$run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC");  

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($run);  
    if($numrows > 0){  
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){  
        $dbname = $row['name'];  
        $dbrating = $row['rating'];  
        $dbwebsite = $row['website'];  
        $dbservice = $row['service'];  
        $dbdate = $row['postdate'];  
        $dbcomment = $row['comment'];  
        $newDate = date("l dS F Y", strtotime($dbdate));  
?>              

<div id="commenttop">  
 <div id="userdetails"><?php echo "{$dbname} - {$dbservice}" ?></div>  
  <div id="rating">  
  <?php   
if ($dbrating == 1) {  
  echo '<img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /> <img src="images/star.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />';  
}  

if ($dbrating == 2) {  
  echo '<img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /> <img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" />';  
}  

if ($dbrating == 3) {  
  echo '<img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /> <img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" />';  
}  

if ($dbrating == 4) {  
  echo '<img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /> <img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/star.png" width="20" height="20" />';  
}  

if ($dbrating == 5) {  
  echo '<img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /> <img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" /><img src="images/activestar.png" width="20" height="20" />';  
}  
?>  
  </div>  
</div>  

<div id="commentbtm"><?php echo "$dbcomment"?>  
<div id="date"><?php echo $newDate?></div>  
</div>  

<?php      
        }  
    }  
    else  
        echo "No Comments Found";  
?>  
        </div> 
        </div>  
        </div>
```