# Getting SVG container size in snapSVG?

Tags: javascript, height, width, snap.svg

What is the correct way to get the size of the 'paper' object with SnapSVG, as soon as it has been created?

My HTML looks something as follows:

```
<div id="myContainer" style="width: 900px; height: 100px" />
```

And then the Javascript code:

```
function initViewer(elementId) {
    var element, elementRef, snap;
    elementRef = '#' + elementId;
    element = $(elementRef);
    element.append('<svg style="width: ' + element.width() + 'px; height: ' + element.height() + 'px; border: solid 1px black;"/>');
    snap = Snap(elementRef + ' svg');
    console.log(snap.getBBox());
}
```

What I observe here is the bounding box has '0' for all attributes, so I can't rely on the bounding box values here. Are there any ways of doing this, without have to go to a parent element?

What I am essentially wanting form all this is the width and the height of the SVG, so I can draw the shapes of the appropriate size for the view.

JS Fiddle, illustrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ajmas/kdnx2eyf/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getBBox() on a canvas returns the bounding box that contains all elements on that canvas. Since there are no elements in your SVG, it returns all 0s.

But the SVG element is just like any other DOM element - you could get its width and height in a number of different ways. You could retrieve the object by ID or whatever and use .offsetWidth or .offsetHeight.

You could also traverse the object itself. I have no idea if this works on all browsers but if you really want to use the snap object, you could do this:

```
snap=Snap(elementRef + ' svg');
snap.node.clientHeight
snap.node.clientWidth
```

But you also just set the height and width of it using the div it is contained in. Why can't you just use element.width() and element.height()?

Comment: This doesn't work on full-screen SVG. It always return zero.

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean by full screen - is the svg element being sized by css? At any rate, other methods should still work here - get the element width and height or use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

Answer (score 0):

I find that `getBBox()` doesn't work on a paper (a Snap "drawing surface"), only on *elements* in a paper. But `node.clientWidth` works for me for Snap.svg papers. Demo below.

```js
var paper = Snap("#mySVG");
paper.rect(0, 0, 200, 100).attr({fill : "#cde"});
//var tMessage0 = paper.getBBox().width;  // throws an error
var tMessage1 = paper.text(4, 24, "paper width = " + paper.node.clientWidth);
var tMessage2 = paper.text(4, 48, "text width = " + tMessage1.getBBox().width);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.1.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<body>
  <svg id="mySVG" width="200" height="100">
  </svg>
</body>
```