# Find font size to fit text into a specific width using pure JS

Tags: javascript, text, size, width, pixel

Given a string of any length in any font (not necessarily monospace, preferably Arial) I need a way to find the font size that will make the text fit perfectly into a specific pixel width, say 500 for example.

I'd MUCH prefer if there were a way to do this without using any libraries, CSS, or html. Pure JavaScript.

Thanks in advance!

---

P.S. I've heard of ctx.measureText(string).width but I couldn't figure out if it was helpful or not...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried taking the pixel width and dividing by string.length. However that obviously only works with mono-space fonts.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25467363/1819684?

Comment: Thanks for that! Using the information I found from that link I was able to construct my own function that solves this problem:

`getFontSize = function(text, targetWidth, font){
 var size = 1;
 ctx.font = size + 'px ' + font;
 
 while(ctx.measureText(text).width < targetWidth){
  size++;
  ctx.font = size + 'px ' + font;
 }
 
 return size;
}`