# How to know the pixel length of strings in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I need to display rectangles with text inside them, all above some specific words of a text. To know the size of the rectangle to display, I need to know de length (in pixels) of the word above of which the rectangle will be.

I know it's possible to know the [length of a string in JavaScript/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057682/determine-pixel-length-of-string-in-javascript-jquery), but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it natively in Angular 6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Answer (score 3):

the "angular" way to do this is with the ViewChild(ren) decorator.

view child:

in html tag your element:

```
<span #widthTarget>my text</span>
```

in controller:

```
@ViewChild('widthTarget')
widthTarget: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() { //view children must be accessed at this hook or later
  console.log(this.widthTarget.nativeElement.width);
}
```

for multiple elements, use the ViewChildren decorator with it's associated functions.

You could also pull this off with a directive of some kind but it depends on your actual use case.

Comment: Great solution! I only had to change the "width" attribute to "offsetWidth", as with "width" I was getting "undefined" as result. The precision of the width is acceptable, as it doesn't include the decimal fraction. Thanks!

Comment: the property used depends on the width / display setting of the element. clientWidth is usually a good option as well.