# Can I validate the <marquee>?

Tags: html, validation, onmouseover, marquee

Is there a way to validate the  tag? And I have two elements with OnMouseOver attribute, and the validator, too don't validate them. The only errors are these. So if you know a way, please share...

Comment: Or if you know a javascript, that is like the marquee...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to validate the `<marquee>` tag since it is not a standard html element. You will have to use JavaScript. Here is another SO question that might lead you in the right direction. [Javascript Marquee to replace  tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337330/javascript-marquee-to-replace-marquee-tags)

Comment: There are several links in the question I posted that can help you. One of them you can try is http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/ . It's a JQuery plugin that should be pretty simple to setup.

Answer (score 1):

`<marquee>`? Are you travelling in time and came from late 90's?

OK, jokes aside. `<marquee>` is not a standard HTML attribute, it was introduced by Microsoft and was never really adopted. Hence the HTML validator will obviously scream.

Technically you can use tricks like generating this tag dynamically via JavaScript. There is also much better, portable and widely accepted workaround - **don't use it**. It looks terrible.

Answer (score 0):

`<marquee>` is not a valid HTML tag. It won't validate.