# Multiple DIV inside DIV - new line in IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

My using below code

```
<div>
<MARQUEE>
<ul>
<li>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</li>
</ul>
</MARQUEE>
</div>
```

The problem is that 1,2,3 are displayed vertically. This happening only in IE7. What i have to change for this to display this in horizontally?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: note this happens in Chrome too ... and should happen in all browsers are a `div` is a block element

Comment: Except IE7, its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please don't use the marquee HTML tag](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee)

To make `div` elements display horizontally try something like this :

```
​ul li div {
    float:left;
}​
```

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ByEKc/)

Comment: The example you have provided to me also contains "MARQUEE" tag. Can you give me replacement of "MARQUEE" tag.Thanks

Comment: The link is to the official HTML specification showing you that Marquee has been deprecated ... for alternatives see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337330/javascript-marquee-to-replace-marquee-tags