# How to remove trailing space from marquee?

Tags: html, css, marquee

I Develop a marquee which continuously moves to upward direction.

But what the exact problem is after finishing scrolling last image there is a huge gap between first image and last image. I just want to remove the trailing space which additionally add to the bottom of the last image. Is anybody help me to figure out the solution. Thanks in advance.

**HTML :**

```
<div style="margin-left:760px;border:0px;height:300px; width:265px;">
    <marquee bgcolor="transparent" scrollamount="8" direction="up" width="265px;" style="float:left; position:absolute;" loop="true" height="300px" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
        <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/bab6pd5wd/i05.jpg" width="220" style="z-index:11;" />
        <br>
        <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/84qkz5na5/i06.jpg" width="220" />
        <br>
        <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/nxvjfma71/i07.jpg" width="220" />
        <br>
        <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/lf9uexogt/i08.jpg" width="220" />
        <br>
        <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/g6eth261p/i09.jpg" width="220" />
        <br>
        <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/wvg9cz2n1/i10.jpg" width="220" />
        <br>
    </marquee>
</div>
```

What i did is just here : http://jsfiddle.net/vivekbhintade/xuwN2/13/

Comment: the `<marquee>` tag isn't good practice, it's a relatively dated technique which now has better counter parts in [CSS animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) and [jQuery .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: `marquee` is outdated mate...look for jquery plugins instead!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move text continuously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818572/move-text-continuously)

Comment: I didn't even know this tag existed!

Comment: Yes you are right but is there any solution for my current question?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the last `<br>` from your marquee should do it, plus check your css and make sure that there is no margin added to images there.

As others have pointed out, using the `<marquee>` tag is really bad practice nowadays. There are lots of very nice jquery marquee plugins if you have a look around.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
<style type="text/css">

.container{
position: relative;
width: 200px; /*marquee width */
height: 200px; /*marquee height */
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
border: 3px solid orange;
padding: 2px;
padding-left: 4px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var zxcMarquee={

 init:function(o){
  var mde=o.Mode,mde=typeof(mde)=='string'&&mde.charAt(0).toUpperCase()=='H'?['left','offsetWidth','top','width']:['top','offsetHeight','left','height'],id=o.ID,srt=o.StartDelay,ud=o.StartDirection,p=document.getElementById(id),obj=p.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0],sz=obj[mde[1]],clone;
  p.style.overflow='hidden';
  obj.style.position='absolute';
  obj.style[mde[0]]='0px';
  obj.style[mde[3]]=sz+'px';
  clone=obj.cloneNode(true);
  clone.style[mde[0]]=sz+'px';
  clone.style[mde[2]]='0px';
  obj.appendChild(clone);
  o=this['zxc'+id]={
   obj:obj,
   mde:mde[0],
   sz:sz
  }
  if (typeof(srt)=='number'){
   o.dly=setTimeout(function(){ zxcMarquee.scroll(id,typeof(ud)=='number'?ud:-1); },srt);
  }
  else {
   this.scroll(id,0)
  }
 },

 scroll:function(id,ud){
  var oop=this,o=this['zxc'+id],p;
  if (o){
   ud=typeof(ud)=='number'?ud:0;
   clearTimeout(o.dly);
   p=parseInt(o.obj.style[o.mde])+ud;
   if ((ud>0&&p>0)||(ud<0&&p<-o.sz)){
    p+=o.sz*(ud>0?-1:1);
   }
   o.obj.style[o.mde]=p+'px';
   o.dly=setTimeout(function(){ oop.scroll(id,ud); },50);
  }
 }
}

function init(){

 zxcMarquee.init({
  ID:'marquee1',     // the unique ID name of the parent DIV.                        (string)
  Mode:'Vertical',   //(optional) the mode of execution, 'Vertical' or 'Horizontal'. (string, default = 'Vertical')
  StartDelay:2000,   //(optional) the auto start delay in milli seconds'.            (number, default = no auto start)
  StartDirection:-1  //(optional) the auto start scroll direction'.                  (number, default = -1)
 });

 zxcMarquee.init({
  ID:'marquee2',     // the unique ID name of the parent DIV.                        (string)
  Mode:'Horizontal', //(optional) the mode of execution, 'Vertical' or 'Horizontal'. (string, default = 'Vertical')
  StartDelay:2000,   //(optional) the auto start delay in milli seconds'.            (number, default = no auto start)
  StartDirection:-1  //(optional) the auto start scroll direction'.                  (number, default = -1)
 });

}

if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", init, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", init)
else if (document.getElementById)
 window.onload=init


</script></head>

<body>
<div id="marquee1" class="container" onmouseover="zxcMarquee.scroll('marquee1',0);" onmouseout="zxcMarquee.scroll('marquee1',-1);">
<div style="position: absolute; width: 98%;">

<p style="margin-top: 0"><b><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/indexb.html">Iframe &amp;
Ajax category added</a></b><br>
The Dynamic Content category has just been branched out with a new
<a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/indexb.html">sub category</a>
to better organize its scripts.</p>
<p><b><a href="http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/gradient/">Gradient Image Maker</a></b><br>
We're excited to introduce our latest web tool- Gradient Image Maker!</p>

<p><b><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/">DD Help Forum</a></b><br>
Check out our new forums for help on our scripts and coding in general.</p>
<p align="left"><b><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/notice.htm">Terms of
Usage update</a></b><br>
Please review our updated usage terms regarding putting our scripts in an
external .js file. </p>

</div>
</div>


<div id="marquee2" class="container" onmouseover="zxcMarquee.scroll('marquee2',0);" onmouseout="zxcMarquee.scroll('marquee2',-1);">
<div style="position: absolute; width: 98%;">

<p style="margin-top: 0"><b><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/indexb.html">Iframe &amp;
Ajax category added</a></b><br>
The Dynamic Content category has just been branched out with a new
<a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/indexb.html">sub category</a>
to better organize its scripts.</p>
<p><b><a href="http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/gradient/">Gradient Image Maker</a></b><br>
We're excited to introduce our latest web tool- Gradient Image Maker!</p>

<p><b><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/">DD Help Forum</a></b><br>
Check out our new forums for help on our scripts and coding in general.</p>
<p align="left"><b><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/notice.htm">Terms of
Usage update</a></b><br>
Please review our updated usage terms regarding putting our scripts in an
external .js file. </p>

</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```