# ASP.NET Masterpage Javascript Marquee Animation Stops when button pressed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Javascript function for Marquee animation in my ASP.NET Masterpage that runs fine when the page is first loaded, but then stops when a page button is pressed.  Any idea how to fix this?

I got help from here, [Javascript Marquee to replace <marquee> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337330/javascript-marquee-to-replace-marquee-tags)

Using the second answer

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    function go() {
        i = i < width ? i + step : 1;
        m.style.marginLeft = -i + 'px';
    }
    var i = 0,
        step = 3,
        space = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    var m = document.getElementById('marquee');
    var t = m.innerHTML; //text
    m.innerHTML = t + space;
    m.style.position = 'absolute'; // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057682/determine-pixel-length-of-string-in-javascript-jquery/2057789#2057789
    var width = (m.clientWidth + 1);
    m.style.position = '';
    m.innerHTML = t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space;
    m.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
        step = 0;
    }, true);
    m.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
        step = 3;
    }, true);
    var x = setInterval(go, 50);
}, true);
```

HTML

```html
<div id="marquee">
    1 Hello world! 2 Hello world! <a href="#">3 Hello world!</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#marquee {
    background:#eee;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Please include **your** code in the question itself. Whay do you mean "page

Comment: Thank you Jon, I've updated it with the code now.  By page, I mena I press a button that is not on the Masterpage, but one of the pages on my website, say Edit Users, and this is when the Javascript function and it's animation fail.  I can see see the "marquee" text, but it stops moving.  Any advice would be great, thanks for responding.

Comment: @RussellWaggoner Is the button you're pressing within an UpdatePanel or something similar, that does not perform a full-page postback?

Comment: @TylerRoper Yes, the button is in an Update panel.  Thanks for responding and anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I will type you an answer now, please hold on just one minute :)

Comment: @TylerRoper Thanks for the code, still having a problem, I'll comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem relates to your button being within an **UpdatePanel** as you mentioned in the comments above. An UpdatePanel will cause the page to postback without re-triggering the *PageLoad* event, so any javascript tied to that will be lost.

*However*, you can use a `PageRequestManager`. This will allow us to also trigger a function *on UpdatePanel postback*. This allows us to run the pageload script both on initial load *and* UpdatePanel postback. The only caveat is that the script block has to come *after your ScriptManager*. I'd suggest moving it just before your `</body>` if possible.

**Basic example:**

```
//Add a page request manager
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

//On postback of UpdatePanel
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    alert("UpdatePanel was just triggered!");
});

//On pageload
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    alert("Initial page load!");
}, true);
```

**Your example:**

```
//Because we now have to call our function on both Page Load AND UpdatePanel postback, let's put it in function
function pageInit() { 
    function go() {
        i = i < width ? i + step : 1;
        m.style.marginLeft = -i + 'px';
    }
    var i = 0,
        step = 3,
        space = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    var m = document.getElementById('marquee');
    var t = m.innerHTML; //text
    m.innerHTML = t + space;
    m.style.position = 'absolute'; // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057682/determine-pixel-length-of-string-in-javascript-jquery/2057789#2057789
    var width = (m.clientWidth + 1);
    m.style.position = '';
    m.innerHTML = t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space + t + space;
    m.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
        step = 0;
    }, true);
    m.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
        step = 3;
    }, true);
    var x = setInterval(go, 50);
}

//Add a page request manager
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

//On postback of UpdatePanel
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    pageInit();
});

//On pageload
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    pageInit();
}, true);
```

If there are certain things you only want to happen on the initial load and *not* on the UpdatePanel postback, you can take them out of the `pageInit()` function and put them back in your `load` event instead.

Comment: Thank you for the code, I'm still not there yet.  The animation does not play like the PageInit() function is not being called.  But I do have an error in the Chrome Javascript Console on this line, var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(), Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined(anonymous function) @ Default.aspx:91

Comment: @RussellWaggoner Try moving the script block to the end of your file before `</body>` instead of being the head.

Comment: Making progress, not quite there.  Moving the javasript below just before the </body> did get the animation of the marquee to work, but I'm still having the same problem with the button click on the page, it is still stoping the animation.  I still get the javascript error that Sys is not defined.  Any help with this would be great, thanks again.

Comment: @RussellWaggoner The script block has to be *after* your ScriptManager. Is this the case, and if not, is it possible to put your ScriptManager earlier in the page?

Comment: Nevermind, it's working now like I wanted.  Thank you so much for this!  Awesome!

Comment: @RussellWaggoner Glad I could help! Please accept my answer above if you wouldn't mind :) I don't generally like to remind people, however seeing as you may be slightly new on SO - Accepting someone's answer provides them with additional reputation and abilities around the site.

Comment: You're right, I lurk here but only posted like once.  I marked your answer with the green check mark so I think that did it Tyler.  Thanks again.

Comment: @RussellWaggoner You rock! Thanks, and no problem.